# Facitility to type accented characters

Tags: feature-request, input-methods

A lot of English-speaking visitors don't have accents on their keyboards. As they are learning French, they may already know alternative ways to type accented characters; but shouldn't the site provide some easy way to to so, and document it in the formatting help?

The [Mathematics Stack Exchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/) has facilities for math formulae, for example.

Accents are an integral part of French so I think we must ensure everyone can type them easily.
At the very least, if we add no special functionality, I think we could document the existing ways somewhere.

Comment: Yeah, and not only just english-speaking visitors, really. Most keyboard layouts do not make it easy to type diacritics. :)

Comment: No problem : ask your question, answer your answer first, without any accent, and a french person put them. I do that in english : I speak english like a spanish cow, and some amical person translate it to oxford english !

Answer (score 5):

Potentially good idea, however on EL&U they seem to have managed to do [IPA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Phonetic_Alphabet) without any clever widgets.

Answer (score 1):

For what it's worth, I have my own keyboard layout for Windows which I use to type French accents, which is based on the UK extended keyboard layout but uses Ctrl+Alt+comma as a meta-key for grave accents, instead of hijacking the backtick key.  it can be downloaded [here](http://game-point.net/misc/keyboard%20layout%20-%20uk%20extended%20enhanced.zip).